# When is it most appropriate to update UITableView height NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

**TL;DR: When UITableView contentSize is correct?**

To update my table height constraint I am using the following function:

```
func adjustHeightOfTableview()
{
    self.myTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    let newHeight = self.myTableView.contentSize.height
    self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

I tried these 2 solutions:

> Calling `adjustHeightOfTableview` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.adjustHeightOfTableview()
    }
```

Result: The table did not appear at all on the screen. I guess it is because content size is 0 when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called first time. Since table height is set to 0, no cell will be created and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not called again

> Calling `adjustHeightOfTableview` after table reload (I have extention for that)

```
extension UITableView
{
    func reloadData(completion: ()->()) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations: { self.reloadData() })
            { _ in completion() }
    }
}

//in my class:
self.relatedTableView.reloadData()
{
     self.adjustHeightOfTableview()
}
```

Result: table was to heigh. Wrong contentSize??

**Bottom line: How and where it is best to update UITableView height NSLayoutConstraint?**

Answer (score 1):

Found it! The answer was here: [Height adjusted UITableView using Auto Layout](http://reactivecookbook.com/post/82883531495/height-adjusted-uitableview-using-auto-layout)

The height **constraint needed to be low priority** and it worked.

I've updated the constraint **both** after reloading table and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as described in the question

[image: height constraint low priority]